# aptana-studio 3 auto-complete problem with php

Tags: aptana

i use aptana-studio 3 on mac for coding php

my problem is auto-complete does not work

But it works well When I press  ctrl-space

The second question

how i can change zen coding key from ctrl-e to ctrl-j

thanks and sorry for my bad English

Comment: One issue per question. Please post the Zen Coding question separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the key-binding, you will have to edit the Zen-Coding 'Ruble'.
As far as I understand, you already have the Ruble in your installed set of Rubles. If not, you will need to grab by clicking 'Command -> Bundle Development -> Install Bundle' and select 'Zen Coding'.

Once you have the Ruble installed, follow the instructions on how to edit the Zen coding Ruble ( http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Modifying+an+existing+Ruble ), and edit the 'expand_abbreviation.rb' file ( https://github.com/aptana/zen-coding.ruble/blob/master/commands/expand_abbreviation.rb ).

Note the cmd.key_binding.mac = "M1+E". You just need to set it as cmd.key_binding.mac = "M1+J" and restart the studio.

Answer (score 1):

There has been recent work done in Aptana Studio in making content assist (auto-complete) pop up automatically more often across languages. This should improve in the 3.0.3 release. If you like, you can try beta versions of that by visiting here: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Changing+the+Update+Type

Comment: you may also add yourself as a watcher on http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2836 which will improve the support for the 3.0.4 release.